# Getting maven release version after release:perform

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, release

I'm using Jenkins and the Maven-Release plugin. In my pom the version is 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.
While executing the release plugin the version is changed into 1.0.1 as i would expect. However, when the release task is complete i'm requesting the ${POM_VERSION} which is 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT altough i would it expect to be 1.0.1. How can i retrieve the release version in Jenkins?

Comment: Please provide more information about how you're *"requesting the `${POM_VERSION}`"*

Comment: I'm getting the ${POM_VERSION} via the jenkins Maven plugin because i use a maven project job

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this in a Jenkins pipeline script ? 
If yes there is something like this:

```
def mavenModel = readMavenPom(file: 'pom.xml')
def releaseVersion = mavenModel.version
```

Comment: No, i'm using a maven project. No external scripts. Is the model the same as the ${POM_VERSION}?

Comment: That it will not work. and no it is not the same as `${POM_VERSION}` cause it's parsed before the job starts...